# fill NaN with another lookup table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, nan

Is there a way to fill the `NaN` with value for `test=default` by matching name, reticle and cell rev?

[image]

[image]

with the few variables in "test" column:
[image]

Is there a way to update the values from others row ? as the datatype "do" would have higher precedence than int and drop the "do" data row?

data:
test  datatype name value   reticle cell_rev
default int s   0x45        CR1
default int s   0xCB        CR3
default do  s   0.68        CR1

I'd like to get:

test  datatype name value   reticle cell_rev
default int s   0.68        CR1
default int s   0xCB        CR3

Comment: You should include examples as text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshaping, then [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) for add missing values and last reshape to original by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['name','value_old','reticle','test','cell_rev'])
       .unstack()
       .ffill()
       .stack()
       .reset_index()

print (df)
  name value_old reticle     test cell_rev value_new
0    s      0x8E     A28  default      CR1      0x8C
1    s      0x8E     A28  default      CR3      0x8E
2    s      0x8E     A28     etlc      CR1      0x8C
3    s      0x8E     A28     etlc      CR3      0x8E
```

EDIT by comment:

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by subset `df1` created by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then fill `NaN` values by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df.ix[df.test == 'default']
print (df1)     
      test name value_old reticle cell_rev value_new
0  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR1      0x8E
1  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR3      0x8C

df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on=['name','reticle','cell_rev'], suffixes=('','1'))
print (df2)
      test name value_old reticle cell_rev value_new    test1 value_old1  \
0  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR1      0x8E  default       0x8E   
1  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR3      0x8C  default       0x8E   
2     etlc    s      0x8E     A28      CR1      0x44  default       0x8E   
3     etlc    s      0x8E     A28      CR3      0x44  default       0x8E   
4      mlc    s      0x1E     A28      CR1       NaN  default       0x8E   
5      mlc    s      0x1E     A28      CR3       NaN  default       0x8E   
6      slc    s      0x2E     A28      CR1       NaN  default       0x8E   
7      slc    s      0x2E     A28      CR3       NaN  default       0x8E   

  value_new1  
0       0x8E  
1       0x8C  
2       0x8E  
3       0x8C  
4       0x8E  
5       0x8C  
6       0x8E  
7       0x8C
```

```
df['value_new'] = df2['value_new'].combine_first(df2['value_new1'])
#df['value_new'] = df2['value_new'].fillna(df2['value_new1'])
print (df)
      test name value_old reticle cell_rev value_new
0  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR1      0x8E
1  default    s      0x8E     A28      CR3      0x8C
2     etlc    s      0x8E     A28      CR1      0x44
3     etlc    s      0x8E     A28      CR3      0x44
4      mlc    s      0x1E     A28      CR1      0x8E
5      mlc    s      0x1E     A28      CR3      0x8C
6      slc    s      0x2E     A28      CR1      0x8E
7      slc    s      0x2E     A28      CR3      0x8C
```

Comment: This solution work nice with sample, but in real data are in column `test` only values `default` and `etlc` ?

Comment: thank you for looking into it, nope, in real data, test column has "default, etlc, Jlc and klc", for jlc and klc, if the value_new is NAN , the NAN should be filled by value  from default and matching with others columns (name, reticle, cell, rev)

Comment: Yes, I have same output. I think if it works with your real data well. sorry.

Comment: it take the last observed value instead of default value, I've added the results to the question, I was unable to attach as text, so attach as image. Any idea on getting always getting the default values? I'm really appreciated your help on this!

Comment: also, it is possible the value_old column has "NAN" value, if this happen, then I will expect the value_old will take default values.

Comment: Ok, please give me a time.

Comment: Thank you! it's work like a charm, and thanks for letting me know the combine first function.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid about answering first, because I feel it is more complicated ;)

Comment: and small advice for another questions - you can check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @jezreal, yesterday I have spent whole day to find a solution for that question, I should ask in here at first place. And I have some others questions, is it possible to overwrite default value with the values from others row as show in above?

Comment: I think better is create new question as edited old one. Then you can get multiple good answers. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, 'value_new'] != df.loc[i, 'value_new']:
        df.loc[i, 'value_new'] = df.loc[(df.test == 'default') &
                                        (df.name == df.loc[i, 'name']) &
                                        (df.reticle == df.loc[i, 'reticle']) &
                                        (df.cell_rev == df.loc[i, 'cell_rev']),
                                        'value_new']
```

I think there's a more efficient solution, but this should work.